# Speed up algorithm pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, numpy

Before turning to the question I have o explain the algorithm that I am using.
For this purpose, say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [[2, [4], None], [4, [9,18,6], None], [6, [], 9],[7, [2], None],[9, [4], 7],[14, [18,6], 3],[18, [7], 1]]
  
# Create a mock pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['docdb', 'cited_docdb','frontier'])
```

Now I will define a distance measure which is 0 whereby the frontier variable is different from NaN.
The algorithm basically updates the distance variable as follows:

1. Look for all docdb having a distance=0 within the variable cited_docdb (which is a list for each observation);
2. Assign a value of 0 to them within cited_docdb;
3. Assign a distance of 1 to all docdb having at least a 0 within their cited_docdb
4. Repeat the process with distance=1,2,3,..., max_cited_docdb (the maximum number of docdb cited)

The algorithm woks as follows:

```
df.replace(' NaN', np.NaN)
df['distance'] = np.where((df['fronteer'] >0), 0, np.nan)
```

```
for k in range(max(max_cited_docdb)):
    s=df.set_index('docdb')['distance'].dropna()[df.set_index('docdb')['distance'].dropna()>=k]
    df['cited_docdb'] = [[s.get(i, i) for i in x] for x in df['cited_docdb']]
    m=[k in x for x in df['cited_docdb']]
    df.loc[m&df['distance'].isna(), 'distance'] = k+1
```

Now, my problem is that my original database has 3 Million of observations and the docdb that cited most other docdb has 9500 values (i.e. the longest cited_docdb list has 9500 values). Hence, the algorithm above is extremely slow. Is there a way to speed it up (e.g. modifying the algorithm somehow with dask??) or not?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a graph problem where you want to get the shortest distance between the nodes in docdb and a fixed terminal node (here NaN).

You can approach this with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/).

Here is your graph:

[image]

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.explode('cited_docdb'),
                            source='docdb', target='cited_docdb',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# get shortest path length (minus bounds = 2)
d = {n: len(nx.shortest_path(G, n, np.nan))-2
     for n in df.loc[df['frontier'].isna(), 'docdb']}
# {2: 2, 4: 1, 7: 3}

# map values
df['distance'] = df['docdb'].map(d).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
   docdb cited_docdb  frontier  distance
0      2         [4]       NaN         2
1      4  [9, 18, 6]       NaN         1
2      6          []       9.0         0
3      7         [2]       NaN         3
4      9         [4]       7.0         0
5     14     [18, 6]       3.0         0
6     18         [7]       1.0         0
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. My main concern is actually about the speed. I know there are other ways to do what my algorithm does but I wonder if this can be done with 3Million of observations in a reasonable amount of time. Thank you again!

Comment: @Lusian the best way is to try. I genuinely cannot tell you, it likely depends on the number of nodes, edges, etc. Try and let me know. If this is too slow, please provide a reproducible example of the complete dataset

Comment: in any case, I would say that there is a problem in the algorithm above as it assumes the presence of a terminal node that does not cite any docdb. This is my bet as I should have better specified what I wanted. Specifically, it might be the case that even the terminal node (6) cites other docdb. The procedure should reproduce the steps 1-4 specified in the main thread. P.s. please let me know how I can give you a reproducible example of my data.

Comment: Can you give a counter example for which my approach wouldn't work? Here what matters is the NaN

Comment: If I understood your example correctly (which I am not sure about), I am not sure of how it would work with these data (in particular what would the terminal node be in this case? The one(s) having one element in the list of cited_docdb?):# initialize list of lists
data = [[2, [4], None], [4, [9,18,6], None], [6, [4,18], 9],[7, [2], None],[9, [4], 7],[14, [18,6], 3],[18, [7], 1]]
  
# Create a mock pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['docdb', 'cited_docdb','frontier'])

Comment: for instance, when I try to apply it to my code it ends up with the following error: "No path between 569328 and nan."